# iptables port forwarding rules only work for first response packet

Tags: iptables, routing, nat

I have the following scenario:

```
+---------------+             +-------------+             +-------------------------+  
|      PC       |             |    Linux    |             |          Router         | 
| 192.168.1.162 | <---------> | 192.168.1.2 | <---------> | 192.168.1.1      WAN_IP | <------ WAN
+---------------+      A      +-------------+             +-------------------------+     B
  Server on TCP                  Have full                      Have no access
   port 9876                      access                      (multiple TCP ports
                                                             forwarded to "Linux")
```

I have a PC in my LAN (under `192.168.1.162`) with a HTTP server on port `9876`. In the same LAN I have a Linux machine (under `192.168.1.2`) that I have full access to. Then there's the router that's connected to the Internet (under `192.168.1.1`) that I have no control over other than emailing the provider and asking them to forward X port to Y IP address. Therefore I asked them in advance to forward a range of TCP port to my Linux machine, where I can decide what to do with them further without having to wait.

What I'm trying to achieve now is a simple TCP port forwarding from WAN TCP port `1234` to my PC TCP port `9876`. My iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.162:9876
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.162 --dport 9876 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
```

The rules work partially, that is only the first response packet sent by PC gets redirected to WAN, the ones that come after don't.
In particular, what I see when sniffing the traffic at point A is the following:

```
Point A:
Source          Destination       Packet
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.162     SYN
192.168.1.162   192.168.1.2       SYN+ACK
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.162     ACK
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.162     PSH+ACK (HTTP GET request)
192.168.1.162   192.168.1.2       PSH+ACK (first part of HTTP response, routed)
192.168.1.162   192.168.1.2       ACK (remainder of HTTP response, not routed)
192.168.1.162   192.168.1.2       ACK (remainder of HTTP response, not routed)
192.168.1.162   192.168.1.2       ACK (remainder of HTTP response, not routed)
```

I determine what does and does not get routed by sniffing the packets at "point B".

IP forwarding is enabled (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding` and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`).

Comment: Can you share the rest of the rules you have? Rules only applying to the first few packets of a connection sounds like it might be related to a conntrack rule